# Angular call function in foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, foreach

In my component I have a foreach loop that is fired when a client is selected. Inside this loop I have to call a function in the same component.

To do this I must use this.functionName() to call the function. But obviously this will not work inside the foreach loop since 'this' is no longer the component itself.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
this.clientService.selectedClient.forEach(function(client) {
    this.getIntake(); // not working
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use arrow functions

```
this.clientService.selectedClient.forEach((client) => {
    this.getIntake(); // not working
});
```

otherwise `this` will not point to the local class instance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank you.

Comment: You can also pass the component as function scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions (See the lexical this part)

Comment: @brk, sure it will.

Comment: @MartineMulder - Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it solved your problem.